# How to search for graduate schools that have Masters in Complexity Science/Complex Systems?

Tags: graduate-school, masters

I'm an undergrad student who is interested in pursuing a Masters degree in complexity science/complex systems in the U.S. I know some schools put this program under physics, math or computer science departments.

I'd like to know which schools that provide such a program. Unlike physics, maths or cs programs, it is not straight-forward to find out such a list. Any recommendations on how to get a complete list of schools that provide a masters degree in complexity science/complex systems?

Comment: I empathize with as I had the same issue (and ended up doing PhD in something else, but trying to hijack it to do things I want).

Comment: BTW: What do you exactly mean by "complex systems" it is a wide term, covering a lot of very different fields. Statistical physics, mathematical modeling in biology, applied mathematics, complex networks, data-mining and machine learning, data science, etc...

Comment: @PiotrMigdal "complex systems" is my edit there, i was checking what the OP meant by complexity science, and a quick google search gave me the impression that the terms are closely related. For instance, wikipedia redirects complexity science to complex systems. Feel free to rollback or re-edit the question, if you feel that it creates ambiguity

Comment: @PiotrMigdal That is the other problem. I think it is a safe a way to narrow down the list after I carefully check their curriculum.

Comment: @PiotrMigdal Another problem is some school may name their program as "non-linear science","system science concentrate on xx", or other term I do not know yet.

Comment: @Joe Also some more good keywords for the search: "collective behavio(u)r", "systems biology".

Comment: @Joe as PiotrMigdal mentions, the main problem is that this definition includes too many fields. It is a bit like saying you are looking for a program in "molecular science". Perhaps if you give us a narrower definition or clearer idea of what you are looking for, we could help you better. For example, what kinds of courses would you like to take? What subfields are you interested in?

Comment: @Bitwise I'm interested in chaos and non-linear phenomena. And I do not want to give up other sub fields unless I have a better understanding of what question they care:) Thanks.

Comment: have you read papers in this subject? if yes, look at the authors affiliations and references.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try looking at speakers from conferences dealing with complex systems, e.g.:

- [European Conference on Complex Systems](http://www.eccs13.eu/)
- [NetSci](http://netsci2013.net/)

You can also search for other conferences (e.g. at http://www.conference-service.com) and then check the speakers. Furthermore, looking at affiliations from recent (say - last few years) papers you like my lead to some good trails.

When it comes to webpages being hubs from complex systems, try looking at:

- http://www.complexssociety.eu
- http://www.network-science.org

Some positions (including doctoral programs) and other resources are at http://www.barabasilab.com.

Also, some group websites are in my collections of links (Delicious: [complexity](https://delicious.com/stared/complexity) and [networks](https://delicious.com/stared/networks) or search at [my Pinboard](https://pinboard.in/search/u%3apmigdal)).

Answer (score 0):

Though [Santa Fe Institute](http://www.santafe.edu/) doesn't have a Master program, it has a [Complex System Course](http://tuvalu.santafe.edu/events/workshops/index.php/Complex_Systems_Summer_School_2013_%28CSSS%29).

Comment: ...and you can look at the second (or the first) affiliation of Santa Fe researchers. Usually they have one.